# VB.NET variable initialization problem on Publish

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is there any way to stop Visual Studio from removing variable initializations prior to publish?

I have a variable:

```
Dim myString as String: myString = Nothing
```

When I click publish, Visual Studio removes ": myString = Nothing"
and then during build it complains "myString is used before it is initialized".  If I do a build (instead of publish) this doesn't happen.

Comment: I don't think VS (or more appropriately, the compiler) is doing what you think it's doing. What makes you think it's removing that? Can you provide a [mcve] showing the issue?

Comment: vb.net/asp.net (per your tag) defaults to `Nothing` so everything after and including your `:` is really unnecessary.  But, if you must the code need  only be: `Dim myString as String = Nothing` So, what am I missing?

Comment: as noted, not aware this should be occurring. Since web pages are state-less, I am not all sure that would matter - but I am not convinced that this code is modified in that manor anyway.

Comment: mason, albert it happens during the publish 100%, I have an open file where the code (regardless of what syntax you use with or without colon fnostro) is initialized, then you run the publish and the initialization code is gone ( I watch it happen in real time).  Whether a web page is state-less is not relevant to this problem.

Comment: Also, I don't have time to create a minimal working example.  The project is very old (vb.net running on old asp.net aspx pages) and so I don't think you can even create this kind of project in VS2019 anymore (maybe you can but I don't have time to dig through google trying to find out exactly what kind of project this is and whether or not VS2019 gives you the option to create it).

Comment: This question is more for anyone who has seen this before and has either found a work around or knows of some option to change to stop this from happening.

Comment: Also, I am sensing people are confusing Build with Publish.  These are 2 different things in VS.  You build all project types.  You publish mostly web apps (clickonce can also be published but lets set that aside).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be more a warning. It's perfectly legal to initialize a string using the colon separator, but likely it's being optimized out.

Your code:

```
Dim myString as String: myString = Nothing
```

is the equivalent of:

```
Dim myString as String = Nothing
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
Dim myString as String
```

as Strings default to Nothing by default, at least in the all the more recent versions of VB/ASP I can find

And as such will trigger that warning.  whether or not it affects your output? that's on you :)

Comment: Yah I'm trying to get rid of unhelpful warnings.  So that is the point of trying to get Visual Studio to be consistent.  Either keep the initialization to satisfy the warning condition, or don't warn me about variables that have been intialized by default.  I don't care which but I don't want to see 100 useless warnings and have to sift through them for useful ones.  I also don't want to have to put in 100 warning exception comments or disable this warning altogether since it does serve a useful purpose.

Comment: For this particular warning, I tend to do this: `Dim s as String = String.Empty` to resolve the warning.

Comment: I can't initialize the string to empty because an empty string in the app means that the variable was initialized and then cleared by a user.  Nothing means that the variable has not yet interacted with the user.  What syntax I use (colon or no colon) doesn't matter either.

Comment: The warning is issued for variable _**use**_ before assignment.  What happens when you wrap the variable in a null/nothing check before use?